# How can I get the same performance from Cython as I am getting from Numba?

Tags: python, performance, cython, numba, static-typing

I am trying to speed up my function in python. My original function is:

```
def SMO(X, y, C, epsilon, tol, max_iter):
        #Initialization
        n = X.shape[0]
        alpha = np.zeros((n))
        b = 0
        count = 0
        while True:
            count += 1
            alpha_prev = np.copy(alpha)
            for i in range(n):
              E_i = np.dot(X[i, :], alpha*y) + b - y[i]
              #if alpha_i doesn't satisfy conditions then we try to optimise it 
              if (E_i*y[i]<-tol and alpha[i]<C) or (E_i*y[i]>tol and alpha[i]>0):  
                #get a random integer not equal to what we already have (i)
                j = i
                while j == i:
                  j = np.random.randint(0, n-1)
                
                eta = 2 * X[i,j] - 2
                if eta == 0:
                    continue
                # store current alpha values    
                alpha_j, alpha_i = alpha[j], alpha[i]

                # calculate values for L and H
                if y[i] != y[j]:
                  L, H = max(0, alpha_j - alpha_i), min(C, C - alpha_i + alpha_j)
                else:
                  L, H = max(0, alpha_i + alpha_j - C), min(C, alpha_i + alpha_j)

                E_j = np.dot(X[j,:], alpha*y) + b - y[j]

                # Set new alpha values and b value
                alpha[j] = alpha_j - y[j] * (E_i - E_j)/eta
                alpha[j] = max(alpha[j], L)
                alpha[j] = min(alpha[j], H)
                alpha[i] = alpha_i + y[i]*y[j] * (alpha_j - alpha[j])
                b1 = b - E_i - y[i] * (alpha[i] - alpha_i) - y[j] * (alpha[j] - alpha_j) * X[i,j]
                b2 = b - E_j - y[j] * (alpha[j] - alpha_j) - y[i] * (alpha[i] - alpha_i) * X[i,j]
                if alpha[i]>0 and alpha[i]<C:
                  b = b1
                elif alpha[j]>0 and alpha[j]<C:
                  b = b2
                else: 
                  b = (b1 + b2)/2    

            # Check convergence
            diff = np.linalg.norm(alpha - alpha_prev)
            if diff < epsilon:
                break

            if count >= max_iter:
                #print("Iteration number exceeded the max of %d iterations" % (max_iter))
                return alpha, b
        
        return alpha, b
```

and it takes around 26ms to run. I thought this function would be good to implement in Cython because of the for loop and there's a lot of indexing going on. Here's my Cython attempt:

```
%%cython --annotate
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
def C_SMO(double[:,:] X, double[:] y, float C, float epsilon, float tol, int max_iter):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j
    cdef int count
    cdef double L, H, b, b1, b2, alpha_j, alpha_i, E_i, E_j, eta, diff
    #Initialization
    n = X.shape[1]
    cdef double[:] alpha = np.zeros((n))
    cdef double[:] alpha_y = np.zeros((n))
    b = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        alpha_prev = np.copy(alpha)
        for i in range(n):
            alpha_y[i] = alpha[i] * y[i]

        for i in range(n):
            E_i = np.dot(X[i, :], alpha_y) + b - y[i]
            #if alpha_i doesn't satisfy conditions then we try to optimise it 
            if (E_i*y[i]<-tol and alpha[i]<C) or (E_i*y[i]>tol and alpha[i]>0):  
                #get a random integer not equal to what we already have (i)
                j = i
            while j == i:
                j = np.random.randint(0, n-1)
                
            eta = 2 * X[i,j] - 2
            if eta == 0:
                continue
            # store current alpha values    
            alpha_j, alpha_i = alpha[j], alpha[i]

            if y[i] != y[j]:
                 L, H = max(0, alpha_j - alpha_i), min(C, C - alpha_i + alpha_j)
            else:
                 L, H = max(0, alpha_i + alpha_j - C), min(C, alpha_i + alpha_j)

            E_j = np.dot(X[j,:], alpha_y) + b - y[j]

            # Set new alpha values and b value
            alpha[j] = alpha_j - y[j] * (E_i - E_j)/eta
            alpha[j] = max(alpha[j], L)
            alpha[j] = min(alpha[j], H)
            alpha[i] = alpha_i + y[i]*y[j] * (alpha_j - alpha[j])
            b1 = b - E_i - y[i] * (alpha[i] - alpha_i) - y[j] * (alpha[j] - alpha_j) * X[i,j]
            b2 = b - E_j - y[j] * (alpha[j] - alpha_j) - y[i] * (alpha[i] - alpha_i) * X[i,j]
            if alpha[i]>0 and alpha[i]<C:
                b = b1
            elif alpha[j]>0 and alpha[j]<C:
                b = b2
            else: 
                b = (b1 + b2)/2    

        # Check convergence
        diff = np.linalg.norm(alpha - alpha_prev)
        if diff < epsilon:
            break

        if count >= max_iter:
            #print("Iteration number exceeded the max of %d iterations" % (max_iter))
            return alpha, b
        
    return alpha, b
```

This code takes around 30ms to run so if anything I've made it worse. Also deactivating bounds checking doesn't seem to help like I thought it would due to all the indexing.

Is there anything I can improve on here? Also when I write `@jit(nopython=True)` above the original function it runs in 680μs. So if there's not much I can do to my Cython code, why does Numba provide such a speed-up?

Comment: Cython can't really convert numpy code. So if most of the time in your computation is happening in numpy then Cython may only add overhead. You may write your own custom functions that replace numpy code. It is best to benchmark which part of the code is slowing you down the most and try and figure out why.

Comment: To complete the comment of @NiteyaShah, Numpy perform a lot of checks that are quite expensive for small arrays regarding the time to compute them. Theses checks cannot be avoided unless the Numpy code is recompiled (which is apparently not the case). Some checks are even calling slow Python functions... Numba do not perform a lot of checks, *reimplement almost all Numpy functions* and compile them directly with your function thanks to JIT compilation (at the expense of a bigger compilation time).